# How do I paint a primitive inside of e.g. Ellipse?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ellipse

I have an Ellipse
  is looking like as shown at the pic. I need to paint a primitive inside of given Ellipse, something like it is shown.

XAML:

```
<Ellipse
            Width="300"
            Height="200"
            Fill="Yellow"/>
```

Picture: [image: Ellipse]

**Update:**
As it's seen I have User Control. Essentially it's an Ellipse in base. Also there are some primitives which have to be located within given Ellipse. Also I need to hide/expose those primitives separately via Bindings.

**The major issue is:** just try to put UC into MainWindow to see what will happen. The primitives just will go away from their coordinates. Also if I encrease/decrease the size of UC itself, it won't scale by proper way.

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Painting_test.UC_Ellipse"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Painting_test"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="300"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>


        <Ellipse
            Width="200"
            Height="200"
            Fill="Yellow"
            Stroke="Black" />
        <Path x:Name="Bridge"
            Width="34.5"
            Height="69.5"
            Margin="115.5,127,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Data="M149,127 L115.5,195.5"
            Fill=" Yellow"
            Stretch="Fill"
            Stroke="Black" />
        <Path x:Name="Nose"
            Width="38.5"
            Height="1.008"
            Margin="115.5,195.5,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Data="M115.5,196.492 L153,196.5"
            Fill=" Yellow"
            Stretch="Fill"
            Stroke="Black" />
        <Rectangle x:Name="SquareEye"
            Width="24"
            Height="24"
            Margin="103.984,118,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Fill="Yellow"
            Stroke="Black" />
        <Ellipse x:Name="CircleEye"
            Width="24"
            Height="24"
            Margin="169,118,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Fill="Yellow"
            Stroke="Black" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Either add it after the Ellipse in XAML so it will be drawn on top of it or fill the Ellipse with a DrawingBrush.

Comment: Hello Klaus, I remember your bike.)) Thanks for quick replying, I'll try that.

Comment: If I use a DrawingBrush I won't able to control to primitive which is inside of the Ellipse. Will it? E.g. a control to Visibility property.

Comment: Can you please add this additional requirement to your question with some examples what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hello Klaus, I made some additional comments. Please find them above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Canvas` instead of `Grid` as a container, and you need to use Canvas Left/Top instead of `Margin`, like this:

```
<Viewbox 
        Stretch="Uniform" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Canvas Width="200" Height="200">
        <Ellipse
            Canvas.Left="0"
            Canvas.Top="0"
            Width="200"
            Height="200"
            Fill="Yellow"
            Stroke="Black" />
        <Path x:Name="Bridge"
              Width="34.5"
              Height="69.5"
              Canvas.Left="65.5"
              Canvas.Top="63"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Data="M149,127 L115.5,195.5"
              Fill=" Yellow"
              Stretch="Fill"
              Stroke="Black" />
        <Path x:Name="Nose"
              Width="38.5"
              Height="1.008"
              Canvas.Left="65.5"
              Canvas.Top="145.5"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Data="M115.5,196.492 L153,196.5"
              Fill=" Yellow"
              Stretch="Fill"
              Stroke="Black" />
        <Rectangle x:Name="SquareEye"
                   Width="24"
                   Height="24"
                   Canvas.Left="53.984"
                   Canvas.Top="68"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Fill="Yellow"
                   Stroke="Black" />
        <Ellipse x:Name="CircleEye"
                 Width="24"
                 Height="24"
                 Canvas.Left="119"
                 Canvas.Top="68"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Fill="Yellow"
                 Stroke="Black" />
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Wow! It works! ) Is there a way to groupe e.g.  Bridge and Nose, SquareEye and CircleEye without losing of achived properties? In order to e.g., to hide both eyes simultaneously.

Comment: sure, stick them in their own child canvas and  turn visibility on and off for the child canvas

Comment: Dean I'm not so familiar with this resource in terms how to control it properly (pretty odd engine). Just added an issue, please  find it as second answer or whatever.

Comment: If you want it to automatically resize, stick it in a ViewBox (I have edited the code for this)

Comment: Dean, you want to say that standard Ellipse (from Toolbox) sits also in a ViewBox container. And why is it not allowed to add second  UC after our alterations.

Comment: To be exact, while adding the second one, disappears the first one.

Comment: Solved it by myself. it needed to put UC instance in a Grid container, first.